# Do after specific time, Android Runnable

Tags: android, timer, runnable

Ive got an app with a class that implements Runnable. Where a thread is started and the run() methid overridden. This runs my graphics.

1.st question : how often is the run() called upon? i havent set a time for this so it must be a default value?

2.nd question : i want stuff to be done after a certain amount of time (2min,5min,10min) etc. What would be the best way to go about doing this, i was thinking about using an int as an counter and once it hits a specific value does what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.st question : how often is the run() called upon? i havent set a time for this so it must be a default value?**

The `run()` method in your Thread is called when you call it eg. `yourThread.start();`

**2.nd question : i want stuff to be done after a certain amount of time (2min,5min,10min) etc. What would be the best way to go about doing this, i was thinking about using an int as an counter and once it hits a specific value does what i want.**

There are to options. Either you could call `Thread.sleep()` method (NB: Never do this in your UI thread).

Or you can do it the way you described above. So in your `run()` method you would have a `while()` loop and check on every iteration if the difference of the lastUpdate and the current time in milli seconds is bigger than the wanted period eg. 2 min, 5 min or 10 min.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 2 - use [ScheduledExecutor](http://nick-lab.gs.washington.edu/java/jdk1.5b/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutor.html)

Answer (score 0):

> 1.st question : how often is the run() called upon?

You can find out for yourself, put this at the start of your Runnable:

```
Log.v("Running Runnable", System.currentTimeMillis() + "");
```

> 2.nd question : i want stuff to be done after a certain amount of time (2min,5min,10min) etc.

Extend a [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) (it initializes the Looper for you!), add a Handler as a class variable, and use the Handler's [`postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) or [`postAtTime()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postAtTime%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) methods.

Answer (score 0):

The exact amount of time in between calls to run() depends on the processor. The time between each call is the sort of thing that's really visible by the nanosecond. If you're trying to create a timer, I'd recommend using System.currentTimeMillis(), calling it in the run() method, and once the difference is greater than or equal to 1000 milliseconds, the actual timer decrements by one. This will keep track of seconds, and you can use it as a base for minutes and generating other events at specific times.